# WordPress MetaQuery Time

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a working metaquery that queries custom post type from certain start time. Let say I have a collection of establishment; some establishment have a normal business hours which is under the 24 hours clock.

E.g
From 8am to 5pm, 2pm to 10pm

However, when the establishment have unusual business hours my code, doesn't display anything.

E.g 10pm to 5am, 6pm to 2am

my meta query

```
$metaCondition = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => $day . '_hh_start_one',
            'value' => date("H:i:s", strtotime($htime)),
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'TIME'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => $day . '_hh_end_one',
            'value' => date("H:i:s", strtotime($htime)),
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'TIME'
        )
    );
```

It works perfectly for 12pm backwards, but for when query with unusual business hours, it won't return any custom post at all.

I have been adding and tweaking my query but I failed. Any lights up there on what I need to do next or what I am missing?

Comment: 24 hour clock includes noon and even dawn time.

Comment: I'm just trying to clarify your penultimate paragraph - you meant '12.00am'

Comment: It's any time, no one know what will user will enter. Any establishment can end any time.

Comment: So clearly grabbing only the time component of a date is not going to work

Comment: I suggest you forget all this PHP stuff for now. Focus on writing a working SQL query, and then reverse engineer that as required